# is connecting high end high power leds in series feasible and are there light quality or other issues

Tags: led, heatsink, dimming

i'm building high power high CRI cine lighting mostly to illuminate softboxes and have chosen Cree XLamp CMT2850 LED 1400mA 36V (Fidelity 95plus CRI).

I plan to build about 12 units for the studio.

I will be using 4 LEDs per unit with total wattage when fully powered 50.4W x4 = 201.6W which will be fitted onto 15cm X 20cm X 1cm copper bar with extra heat sinks connected to the rear of this to keep operation temp below 85C. The drivers will have a 1-10V dimming included to get the right strength of light.

I have a choice of using 4 drivers 1400mA 36V (1 per LED)
or 2 drivers @1400ma 72V with 2 LEDs connected in series.
i don't want to go up to 144V with 4 LEDs in series due to the units being touched and don't want that kind of potential voltage coming into human contact.

**my question is** will running two high end LEDs connected in series affect in any way their performance , the colour temp (K) or the CRI performance , or affect the life of the LEDS ?

Comment: Series is usually recommended for LEDs since it ensures that they have equal current. Using more smaller LEDs may be preferable since it will give more uniform illumination.

Comment: Thank you, The softboxes and focus lenses that can be attached if required use a Bowens mount which is a 10cm diameter fitting attached to the front face of the copper heat sink. All the LED's need to fit within this space. 4 Cree 2850's occupy a 5.6cm  X 5.6cm square. which leaves 2.2cm per flat side free. and 1.1cm on the diagonal. so it seems to be about as spread out as it can be.  Using a soft box helps smooth out the illumination. each led has about a 120 degree spread

Comment: multiple drivers provide redundancy

Answer (score 1):

High power LEDs usually *are* strips of several LEDs in series, packaged in the same housing. You can tell when they are because the forward voltage will be higher than 3~4 volts; a single blue, violet, or white LED has a forward voltage in that range, so if your LED has a 36 volt forward voltage, I'd guess there's between 10 and 12 LEDs in series on it, and possible a few strings of those in parallel. Putting more in series isn't a problem if you can supply the requisite voltage. Note that putting more in parallel isn't a good idea, though, without giving each one its own driver; paralleling LEDs requires careful matching of their forward voltages, which is easy to do if you can test and sort tens of thousands of them, but likely impossible if you only have a handful to work with.

More of a problem is the voltage. You say you're using 72 V for two in series, but also that you don't want to go to 144 V for four because of the possibility of touching them. 50 volts is the maximum for anything to be considered extra-low voltage as defined by the IEC, and I personally wouldn't want to put more than about 30 volts on anything that can be touched. I recommend you seal these so that they can't be touched, and then put all four in series, assuming you can easily provide the requisite current at 144 V.